# Djago dependent dropdown list using AJAX jQuery not working in Template

Tags: jquery, django, django-models, django-forms, django-ajax-selects

im doing a django dependent form and it works for my create view but not in update view. I tink the problem is the jQuery cdn library, i think its a conflict with the bootstrap cdn. The AJax call does not fire. Any idea maybe there is a simpler way to do dependent forms in django? If you have a solution i gladly want your help

i followed the eample provided by Vitor Freitas
thx Theo

Models view:

```
class Profession(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    profession_icon = models.ImageField(_("profession icon"), upload_to='profession_icon/%Y/%m/%d/', height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=None, blank=True, validators=[validate_image_file_extension])


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Professioncategory(models.Model):
    profession = models.ForeignKey(Profession, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Skills(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    active = models.BooleanField(_('Active'), default=True)
    profession = models.ForeignKey(Profession, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    professioncategory = models.ForeignKey(Professioncategory, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    posted_on = models.DateTimeField(_('Registrerad'), auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(_('last updated'), auto_now=True)
    years_of_exp = models.CharField(_('years of experiance'), max_length=20, choices=YEARS_OF_EXP, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.email

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("users:detail", kwargs={"user_id": self.user.id})

    def geticon(self):
        return self.profession.profession_icon
```

Forms.py

```
class SkillsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Skills
        fields = ['profession','professioncategory', 'years_of_exp','active']
        
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['professioncategory'].queryset = Professioncategory.objects.none()

            if 'profession' in self.data:
                try:
                    profession_id = int(self.data.get('profession'))
                    self.fields['professioncategory'].queryset = Professioncategory.objects.filter(profession_id=profession_id).order_by('name')
                except (ValueError, TypeError):
                    pass  # invalid input from the client; ignore and fallback to empty professioncategory queryset
            elif self.instance.pk:
                self.fields['professioncategory'].queryset = self.instance.profession.professioncategory_set.order_by('name')
```

Views.py

```
class SkillsCreateView(SuccessMessageMixin,CreateView):
    model = Skills
    form_class = SkillsForm
    success_message = "Skill added"
    template_name = 'users/user_skill_add.html'

    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super(SkillsCreateView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
         return reverse("users:detail", kwargs={"pk": self.request.user.pk})



user_skills_view = SkillsCreateView.as_view()

class SkillsUpdate(SuccessMessageMixin,UpdateView):
    model = Skills
    form_class = SkillsForm
    success_message = "Skill updated"
    template_name = 'users/user_skill_add.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("users:detail", kwargs={"pk": self.request.user.pk})

   

user_skills_update_view = SkillsUpdate.as_view()

class SkillsDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Skills
    template_name = 'users/user_skill_delete.html'


    def get_success_url(self):
         return reverse("users:detail", kwargs={"pk": self.request.user.pk})

      
user_skills_delete_view = SkillsDelete.as_view()
```

AJAX view

```
def load_professions(request):
    profession_id = request.GET.get('profession')
    professioncategorys = Professioncategory.objects.filter(profession_id=profession_id).order_by('name') 
    return render(request, 'users/professioncategory_dropdown_list_options.html', {'professioncategorys': professioncategorys})
```

HTML from AJAX

```
<option value="">--------</option>
{% for professioncategory in professioncategorys %}
<option value="{{ professioncategory.pk }}">{{ professioncategory.name }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

JS code in HTML Form

```
    <form method="post" id="SkillsForm" data-professions-url="{% url 'users:ajax_load_professions' %}" novalidate>
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ form|crispy }}
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"><i class="mdi mdi-update"></i> {% trans "Update" %} </button>
                    </form>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3245234342342342342344/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
    $("#id_profession").change(function () {
      var url = $("#SkillsForm").attr("data-professions-url");
      var professionId = $(this).val();


      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: {
          'profession': professionId
        },
        success: function (data) {
          $("#id_professioncategory").html(data);
        }
      });

    });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue, the problem was that the def__init__ method in the form was not aligned with the class

A